# If $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a shift $B$, is it then true, that $A^n x \perp A^m x \Rightarrow B^n x \perp B^m x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I don't think so, as we have:

$$A U = U B$$

$$A = U B U^{-1}$$

$$A^n x \perp A^m x$$

$$U^n B^n U^{-n} x \perp U^m B^m U^{-m} x$$

$$U^{n-m} B^n x \perp B^m U^{n-m} x$$

So it's only true if $n = m$ here.

---

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to show, that every isometric $A$ in $\mathcal{H}$ is unitarily equivalent to a shift $B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ as to the existence of such a subspace $H$ for which $$x \in H \quad A^n x \perp A^m x$$ $$\mathcal{H} = H \oplus AH \oplus A^2 H \oplus \ldots$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show an isometry is unitarily equivalent to a shift (Wold decomposition).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048131/show-an-isometry-is-unitarily-equivalent-to-a-shift-wold-decomposition) (I mean: does it help you to answer the end of your post? The answer to your initial question being obviously "no")

Comment: @AnneBauval No, because it's still not clear for me. I would understand, why $B^n x \perp B^m x$ as $B$ is the shift. Then it's clear that it's $\perp$ and the second condition too (if we take $\mathcal{H} = \ell^2_H (\mathbb{Z}_+)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space). What's not clear is why $A^n x \perp A^m x$, as $A$ is just an isometric operator and not a shift?

Comment: The line $U^{n-m} B^n x \perp B^m U^{n-m} x$ of your post cannot be derived from the previous one $U^n B^n U^{-n} x \perp U^m B^m U^{-m} x,$ which implies $U^{n-m} B^n y \perp B^m U^{n-m}y$ for $y=U^{-n}x,$ not $y=x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is true (if $m\ne n$ and $AU=UB$ for some unitary $U$) is not $A^nx\perp A^mx\implies B^nx\perp B^mx$ but:
$$A^nK\perp A^mK\iff B^nH\perp B^mH,$$
if $K=UH.$

Proof:

- $\Leftarrow:$ if $B^nH\perp B^mH$ then, forall $y=Ux,y'=Ux'\in K,$
  $$\begin{align}\langle A^ny,A^my'\rangle&=\langle UB^nx,UB^mx'\rangle\\&=\langle B^nx,B^mx'\rangle\\&=0
  \end{align}$$
- $\Rightarrow:$ same proof, exchanging $A$ with $B,$ $H$ with $K,$ and $U$ with $U^{-1}.$

Comment: Thanks. What about this one: $$\mathcal{K} = K \oplus A K \oplus A^2 K \oplus \ldots \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{H} = H \oplus BH \oplus B^2 H \oplus \ldots$$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is the space $A$ is from, and $\mathcal{H}$ is the space $B$ is from

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand. Are you asking a new question? I so, can you formulate it with more detail in a new post?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is the title is "no". Take $H$ a separable Hilbert space with a fixed orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Let $A$ be the unilateral shift, and $B$ the unilateral shift for an orthonormal basis that begins with $(e_1+e_2)/\sqrt2$, $(e_1-e_2)/\sqrt2,e_3$. Put $x=e_1$. Then $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent, and
$$
A^0e_1=e_1\perp e_2=Ae_2,
$$
while
$$
B^0e_1=e_1\not\perp Be_1
$$
since
$$
Be_1=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,B\big[\frac{(e_1+e_2)}{\sqrt2}+\frac{(e_1-e_2)}{\sqrt2}\big]
=\frac1{2}\,({e_1-e_2}+e_3).
$$

In general it is not true that any isometry is unitarily equivalent to a shift, because that fails obviously for the identity operator. What is true is the [Wold Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition), which says that any isometry is a direct sum of a unitary plus a direct sum of unilateral shifts.

Comment: "In general it is not true that any isometry is unitarily equivalent to a shift, because that fails obviously for the identity operator. What is true is the Wold Decomposition, which says that any isometry is a direct sum of a unitary plus a direct sum of unilateral shifts." But that's what I'm telling right now, that it's true, if there is such a space $H$ for which $B^m H \perp B^n H$. I just don't get why it is like that

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. But, since $B$ is an isometry, $B^mH\perp B^nH$ is the same as $B^{m-n}H\perp H$ if $n<m$. If $B$ is the shift for the orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, take 
$$
H=\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{e_{mk}:\ k\in\mathbb N\}.
$$
Then $B^{m-n}e_{mk}=e_{mk+m-n}\not\in H$, so $B^{m-n}H\perp H$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but why is it true, that $A^m H \perp A^n H$? That's what I don't get

Comment: If $A=UBU^*$, then $$\langle A^mx,A^nx\rangle=\langle UB^mU^*x,UB^nU^*x \rangle=\langle B^mU^*x,B^nU^*x\rangle=0.$$

Comment: But why do you take $U B^m U^*$, and not $U^m B^m U^{-m}$?

Comment: And why does the second last equality hold i.e. $\langle U B^m U^* x, ... \rangle = \langle B^m U^* x, ... \rangle$?

Comment: First, $$(UBU^*)^m=UB^mU^*.$$ Second, because $U$ is a unitary (in particular, it is an isometry).